# Autoedit not working with frozen column

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am trying to use the frozen column setup and once I got that working the autoedit setting it not working anymore. Now to enter edit mode for a cell you have to double click to activate the cell, is there a setting or something I need to add to all editing on a single click of a cell versus a double click.

Answer (score 0):

[The source](http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js) for handling the click

```
if (hasFrozenRows) {
  if ((!(options.frozenBottom) && (cell.row >= actualFrozenRow))
       || (options.frozenBottom && (cell.row < actualFrozenRow)) ) {
                scrollRowIntoView(cell.row, false);
  }

  setActiveCellInternal(getCellNode(cell.row, cell.cell));
}
```

wraps the editor display call `setActiveCellInternal` in a check on `hasFrozenRows`. Furthermore, the check is defaulted to `false` and only changes for

```
if (options.frozenRow > -1) {
  hasFrozenRows = true;
//...removed remaining code
}
```

So without setting a grid option of `frozenRow: 0` you'll have to double-click to edit. *Note that the first "data" row corresponds to value `1`.*

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, but when I set frozenRow to 0 I get an js error saying "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" for this line of code var dataLength = getDataLength() || this.data.length;, is there something else I am missing

Comment: See if you can reproduce the issue [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/s6rzjm4p/).

Comment: I believe it is the data that I am working with, so I was not able to reproduce the error in the fiddle you provided but I did get the single click working in my app.  Thank you very much, now it is on to the next issue